# find DataTable cell by data

Tags: datatable

How do I find a single cell in a datatable by looking for the cell data?
Say I have a cell with data "hello". I guess it will be something like `table.cell(this.data == "hello")`but that is not working?

So for instance, take this datatable: https://codepen.io/kickbk/pen/ZEzVymN
How do I find the cell with the value "Airi Satou" (it's on the first row, first cell) and then update the data of the third cell of the row it is on to show "found"?

Comment: Tons of ways, but the question needs more context. Like what do you mean by "find the cell"? By index? By DOM ID? etc..

Comment: @Aaron, I want to find that cell by the value of its data, then find the row the cell is on and update other cells on the same row. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Aaron, I edited my question with a practical example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways, but it really depends on your specific application/situation. The code below will loop through all cells and find the one with value you are looking for. If you have tens of thousands of rows, this won't be very efficient.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.cells().every( function () {
    if ( this.data() == 'hello' ) {
        $(this.node()).addClass( 'foundcell' );
        $(this.node()).parent('tr').addClass( 'foundrow' );
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
} );
```

https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().every()